# How to make Web Scraping faster?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made this code to extrat lyrics from a website informing the artist and the music name.

The code is working, the problem is that I have a DataFrame (named years_1920_2020) with 10000 musics, and it took 1:30h  to retrieve all these lyrics .

Is there a way to do it faster?

```
def url_lyric(music,artist):
 url_list = ("https://www.letras.mus.br/", str(artist),"/", str(music),"/")
 url = ''.join(url_list)
 req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
 try:
   webpage = urlopen(req).read()
   bs = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
   lines =bs.find('div', {'class':'cnt-letra p402_premium'})
   final_lines = lines.find_all('p')
   return final_lines
 except:
     return 0


final_lyric_series = pd.Series(name = "lyrics")

for year in range (1920,2021):
  lyrics_serie = lyrics_from_year(year)
  final_lyric_series = pd.concat([final_lyric_series, lyrics_serie])
  print(year)
```

the function lyrics_from_year(year) uses the function url_lyric, perform some re tasks and return a pd.series with all the lyrics of the chosen year

Comment: There are many ways to make this faster. For example you could use threads and run the requests in parallel. However, you are scraping someone elses web site and you should also think about if your scraping could affect the page! So if you're taking data from a page that doesn't offer an official way, you might want to make scraping slower, not faster.

Comment: Use `Parallel Processing`. Since you know the years from `1920 - 2021` so you can divide it into chunks and process in parallel.

Comment: You can use this article https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-asynchronous-web-requests-in-parallel-with-python-3-5-without-aiohttp-264dc0f8546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the solution using the pythons asyncio module. Please refer to this [Article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-asynchronous-web-requests-in-parallel-with-python-3-5-without-aiohttp-264dc0f8546) It's not an exact solution but similar to your problem.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


def url_lyric(music, artist):
    pass


def lyrics_from_year(year):
    music = None
    artist = None
    return url_lyric(music, artist)


async def get_work_done():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor,
                lyrics_from_year,
                *(year)  # Allows us to pass in arguments to `lyrics_from_year`
            )
            for year in range(1920, 2021)
        ]

    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(get_work_done())
loop.run_until_complete(future)

final_lyric_series = pd.Series(name="lyrics")


for result in future:
    final_lyric_series = pd.concat([final_lyric_series, result])
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how you could do it:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests, bs4

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        urls = [f"https://www.letras.mus.br{x['href']}" for x in bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
            url = 'https://www.letras.mus.br/adele/mais-tocadas.html'
        ).content, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'song-name'})]

        for url in urls:
            async with session.get(url) as r:
                lyrics = bs4.BeautifulSoup(await r.text(), 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'cnt-letra'}).text
                print('\n'.join(x.strip() for x in lyrics.strip().split('\n')))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```